# Will this 22" drawer slide replace the slide mounted to my 18" drawer?

Tags: cabinets

I have a kitchen cabinet with 18" drawers, with slides on the side. The internal depth of them is 23" as is the length of the part of the slide mounted to cabinet.

The inside of my cabinet looks like this:
[image: inside of my cabinet]

My drawer looks like this:
[image: side view of drawer]

I wish to replace the slides because the rear mount is cracked like so:
[image: cracked rear mount]

So my question is will [this 22" slide](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0019FR3IC), [this rear bracket](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000JV9AW4) and [this frame mounting bracket](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000JV307U) work? There only seems to be 22" and 24" brackets and I assume I am somehow measuring wrong.

Replacing just the bracket is an option, but quite frankly none of my drawers in my kitchen slide very smoothly so I'm looking to replace all of them.

Comment: Can you replace the broken mount instead of replacing the entire slide? I had a mount fail as well and was able to find a replacement part at the local hardware store.

Comment: Kevin, that's an option,but quite frankly the drawer does not slide very smoothly, so doing that won't give me the "good as new" satisfaction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use the correct size. [Here](http://www.homedepot.com/h_d1/N-5yc1v/R-202176382/h_d2/ProductDisplay?catalogId=10053&langId=-1&keyword=draw%20slides&storeId=10051) is an 18" one. The 22" will be to long for the draw.

If you use the 18" it will fit the draw, but you will likely need to add wood to the side to allow a place to screw the track into.

EDIT:
You need to add a piece of wood to the side of the cabinet. That wood could be glued and clamped until set. Then screw the side track to that piece of wood.

You may be able to add a board stretching from side to side, then screw the end of the 18" track into that.

I see no easy way unless you find a place that sells that exact slide.

One more thought:
If you used the 22" slide and just fastened the first 18" that came in contact with the draw. It may mean drilling new holes in the slide however if the design is like I think it is, I think that would work. Then you could attach the slide to the front and back as original.

Comment: Steve, so where do I mount the back of the slide to?

Comment: @Justin - Please see my edit.

Comment: So its not normal to put 18" drawers into 23" deep cabinets?

Comment: I have not been able to find a slide like the one you have, but that does not mean they don't exist. If I were doing it, I would do as I said because I think it is a sturdy solution. Only it involves more work. Maybe someone can point to a link that has what you need.

Comment: I had another thought, please see my edit.

Comment: The only problem with your approach is that there is no wall on the left side of the drawer. The drawer is half the width of the cabinet. If I could fasten the drawer side of the slide with three screws, wouldn't that be sturdy enough? If I could find a 22" slide with screw-holes in the right position, and use a one inch block of wood on the back of the cabinet, wouldn't that work out pretty well? If not, I guess I could replace both slides at once, and run a boar across the cabinet at 18" deep to hold the rear mounts.

Comment: apparently great minds think alike. Appreciate the advice!